# How to create a horizontal strip inside a circlular plane?

Tags: edit-mode, faces

I need to create a horizontal strip from one side of the circular plane to another circular plane inside it.
The result needs to be like this:
[image: 1]

I got the outer circles using the inset key like this:
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

I got this now only an intersecting rectanglular face is to be added but i dont know how to.
[image: 4]

Comment: Forgot about it @MrZak. Done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on your final goal but you could do it with the help of the knife tool (<kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>C</kbd> to cut orthogonally). Also, use a *Mirror* modifier to make it simpler:

[image]